# Sticky navigation with full height divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I'm using a JQuery plugin called SMINT to create sticky navigation that becomes fixed to the top of the viewport when scrolling. I'm trying to leave a space before and after the navigation at the top of the page and multiple full height divs below.

Using

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
 box-sizing:border-box;
 }
```

makes the divs full height (minus the sticky nav) but botches the initial navigation. (after scrolling the navigation is fine). Removing the border-box screws up the full-height.

My attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/colintkelly/uxsg6mL8/

Live example: http://www.banditfish.com/black-fives/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any plugin for that - here is a quick and easy to understand/customize
Approach:

[**JSnippet demo - using your HTML without smint**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/268/SMINT-alternative--Create-sticky-navigation-bar-without-any-plugin)

```
var barSelector = ".subMenu",
  offSetToTriggerFixed = 1,
  offsettofix = $(barSelector).offset().top + offSetToTriggerFixed,
  $fixedBar = $(barSelector).eq(0).clone();

//Set cloned style and append to body:
$fixedBar.css({ display:'none', position: 'fixed', top:0, 'z-index':1100});
$('body').append($fixedBar);

//Set heights:
var viewPortHeight = $('body').height(),
    navHeight      = $(barSelector).outerHeight(),
    $anyOtherSec    = $('.section').not('.sTop');
    $anyOtherSec.css({ height: viewPortHeight - navHeight + 5});


//Trigger when needed:
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (fromTop <= offsettofix) $($fixedBar).hide();
    else $($fixedBar).show();
});
```

Comment: OP needs to use that particular plugin and this make current question eligible.  Otherwise it was a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. But i need the .section divs to be 100% height minus the height of the navigation. Unless, I'm missing something, I'm not seeing that in this example.

Comment: @Razvan Dumitru Not using the plugin - is also an answer, OPs especially new guys may think its the best way or the preferred way to achieve something while its allot easier to use your own code.

Comment: @ColinKelly I missed the code for that check the edit

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being super clear. Section 1, Section 2, etc. all need to display at 100% height between the bottom of the nav and the bottom of the viewport.  The height of sTop doesn't matter.

Comment: @ColinKelly Now I get it - fixed it - you know you can do it your self it pretty easy just give it a try, read the code understand and change whatever you need.